# As you see I have specified that I want to send 100 tokens to the address but this is not sending 100 tokens it's send 0.0000001 I dont know why?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, tokens, dapps

Document

## Collage Assigment ERC 20

```
<button>Name</button><br /><br />
<button>Decimal</button><br /><br />
<button>Symbol</button><br /><br />
<button>total supply</button><br /><br />

<button
  onclick="window.open('https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xE87a33CF225dc01Ac4a22d8613343b9f0601040A')"
>
  Smart contract</button
><br />
<br />
<input placeholder="enter wallet adderess" /> <br /><br />
<input placeholder="enter ammount of tokens" />
<br /><br /><button onclick="sendTokens()">Transfer</button> <br /><br />
<span id="status">Loading...</span>

<script>
  const ABI = [
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "account",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "amount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "_burn",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "constructor",
    },
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "owner",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "spender",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: false,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "value",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "Approval",
      type: "event",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "spender",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "amount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "approve",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "bool",
          name: "",
          type: "bool",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "spender",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "subtractedValue",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "decreaseAllowance",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "bool",
          name: "",
          type: "bool",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "spender",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "addedValue",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "increaseAllowance",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "bool",
          name: "",
          type: "bool",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "recipient",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "amount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "transfer",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "bool",
          name: "",
          type: "bool",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "from",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "to",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: false,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "value",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "Transfer",
      type: "event",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "sender",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "recipient",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "amount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "transferFrom",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "bool",
          name: "",
          type: "bool",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "owner",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "spender",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      name: "allowance",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "account",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "decimals",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint8",
          name: "",
          type: "uint8",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "name",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "string",
          name: "",
          type: "string",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "symbol",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "string",
          name: "",
          type: "string",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "totalSupply",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
  ];
  async function loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      window.ethereum.enable();
    } else {
      alert("please install metamask");
    }
  }
  async function load() {
    await loadWeb3();
    window.contract = await loadContract();
    getName();
    getDecimal();
    getSymbol();
    getTotalSupply();
    updateStatus("Ready!");
  }
  function updateStatus(status) {
    const statusEl = document.getElementById("status");
    statusEl.innerHTML = status;
    console.log(status);
  }
  load();
  async function loadContract() {
    return await new window.web3.eth.Contract(
      ABI,
      "0xE87a33CF225dc01Ac4a22d8613343b9f0601040A"
    );
  }
  async function getName() {
    updateStatus("fetching name .......");
    const name = await window.contract.methods.name().call();
    console.log(name);
  }
  async function getDecimal() {
    updateStatus("fetching name .......");
    const decimal = await window.contract.methods.decimals().call();
    console.log(decimal);
  }
  async function getSymbol() {
    updateStatus("fetching name .......");
    const decimal = await window.contract.methods.symbol().call();
    console.log(decimal);
  }
  async function getTotalSupply() {
    updateStatus("fetching name .......");
    const decimal = await window.contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
    console.log(decimal);
  }

  function sendTokens() {
    window.contract.methods
      .transfer(
        "0x9433E8153889e6f7798aEFA266d274435e6F95DA",
        100 * 10 ** 18
      )
      .send({
        from: "0x4e6A54a933A5A3d02611150979Ad3114B6737b09",
        gas: 210000,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: and when I add 100 * 10***18 it give an error saying owerflowed, operation = BigNumber.from()

Comment: How many decimals does the contract have?